# Get desired html element's attribute value and set to hidden field before binding in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say such hidden field has genereated:

```
<input data-val="true" 
       data-val-number="The field MemberRelationId must be a number." 
       id="MemberRelationId" 
       name="MemberRelationId" 
       type="hidden" 
       value="3">
```

As you seem it has a value `3`. It means that, user has already set the value for this field.
But, he(she) can also change this value and I must send the new value to the action method.

Also, the main point is that, user can select new value by clickind one of these `div`s:

```
<div class="collection-container">

    <div class="collection-element selected" data-value="3">
        <span class="icon-check"></span>
        <span>Son</span>
    </div>

    <div class="collection-element " data-value="6">
        <span class="icon-check"></span>
        <span>Father</span>

    </div>

    <div class="collection-element " data-value="8">
        <span class="icon-check"></span>
        <span>Brother</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

For, now I am **manually changing the hidden field value** with `JQuery` after clickin one of these `div`s

```
...
$('#MemberRelationId').val($(this).attr("data-value"));
...
```

But, this way doesn't satisfy me. Is there any better approach in MVC?

***What I want to achieve?***

I want automatically to get selected div and bind `data-value` attribute value to `MemberRelationId`.

Thanks.

***Update:***

Here is the part from the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a dropdownlist to bind to your property (or is this a particular UI requirement)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, this is UI requirement.

Comment: Based on you screen shot you could use radio buttons, but it would involve a fair bit of css.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want to use radio buttons here. If I haven't any option, I will continue to change hidden filed value with jquery. So, have I any another option?

Comment: Not than I am aware of (but just to be clear, you can style radio buttons to look just like your image)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I got it. I will give atry to use radio button. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you like your own solution where you define event for all elements of the collection-element class? 

$(".collection-element").click(function(){
 $('#MemberRelationId').val($(this).attr("data-value"));
});

Comment: @belurd Because, Somebody can chnage the property name in the c# class and forget to change `MemberRelationId` to new id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest solution is to use radio button with style. In fact, your code act as a radio button; the only difference is the `icon-check`, but you can emulate the same interface with `CSS`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the required style. IMHO it is not so possible with radio button.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - your opinion is wrong.  Unless there is some aspect you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Check this sample: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/. It's perfectly possible to emulate that behaviour through CSS

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Ok, I got it. I will give a try to this. I am marking this answer as accepted.